# Find similar values and move cells in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Basically, I have Google Search data for two different months in one Google Sheet. I'm trying to align similar terms with their data for both months.

Here's the Google Sheet -> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Xu5_37aLJW3yBCJ8SbquexNHShMwsApF-2BpBEhpcA/edit#gid=0

As you can see in the Sheet, we have data in Black and Blue color, Black represent July and Blue represent August.

In the sheet, you can see A8 and A9 search terms are also found in Blue (August) at G6 and G7.

How do I move the data so that both months search term aligns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's either first one or second one you seek:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A, G:L, {1,2,3,4,5,6}, 0)))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G:G, A:F, {1,2,3,4,5,6}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]